# spring batch and jrecord to generate ebcedic

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jrecord

I am reading a table in an object and I need to generate a passthrough ebcidic file from it. This is a spring batch step. There was some suggestions to use jrecord to write an aggregator and a FlatFileItemWriter.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

[JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) is possible solution, I can not say whether there is a better solution for you or not as I do not
know anything about Spring-Batch. This is perhaps more of an extended Comment than a pure answer

**JRecord** reads / writes files using a File-Schema (or File Description).
Normally this file-schema is a Cobol-Copybook although it also can be a Xml~Schema. The file schema can also be defined in the Program if need be. Given you want to write **Ebcdic** files, I would think a Cobol-Copybook
will be needed at some stage.

**JRecord** also support for mainframe/Cobol sequential File structures (FB - Fixed-Width files)
which is what you want

**JRecord** allows access to fields either by Field-Name or Field-Index (or field id). Note **Record_Type_index** is to handle files with multiple record types (e.g. header-record, detail-record, footer-record files).

```
 outLine.getFieldValue(record_Type_Index, field_Index).set(...)
```

or

```
 outLine.getFieldValue("Field-Name").set(...)
```

---

Bruce Martin (author of [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/))

---

Discussions continued at JRecord forum

- https://sourceforge.net/p/jrecord/discussion/678634/thread/2709ab72/?limit=25#c009/8287